# Word for letters from a foreign or unknown language

Tags: vocabulary, loanwords

I used to describe these characters as Cyrillic ("I don't understand the cyrillic text on this poster"), but I learned today that Cyrillic is an actual type of script/alphabet! Is there an English word that describes foreign/unknown text?

P.s. I'm talking like reading Russian as an English speaker, not reading French. Actual unknown characters, not just unknown words.

Comment: Do you mean *a foreign alphabet*?

Comment: _Non-Latin_ (though '[s]ome languages have extended the Latin alphabet with ligatures, modified letters, or digraphs.') look at [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabets)

Comment: It's ***greek*** to me ;)

Comment: @ScotM, describing Russian dialect as Greek seems a bit odd to me though :P If there isn't a English word that describes it, foreign alphabet or foreign dialect might be the best way to say it.

Comment: @Nathan [Greek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeking) has a particular meaning.

Comment: "It's Greek to me" is an idiom. It doesn't mean you're actually saying it *is* Greek. It could be Chinese or Russian or Urdu. Or even incomprehensible English, for that matter.

Comment: I don't see a problem here. "I don't understand the characters/script/alphabet/writing/chicken scratch". They all work fine. If you call it an alphabet when it is not technically an alphabet, I would not consider that an error on your part because there's no way to know beforehand

Comment: The subtle distinctions between *character*, *script*, *alphabet*, and *writing* may not be considered worthy of consideration by Everyman, but it seems worthy of an answer for EUL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are hundreds of [written language systems](http://www.omniglot.com/writing/definition.htm) with unique characters. Each writing system has a unique name for its set of characters, which is often (but not always) the name of the language itself. Not all of the writing systems have alphabets. For example:

> [Chinese](http://www.ancientscripts.com/chinese.html) has ***logographic*** characters representing morphemes.
>
> [Japanese](http://www.ancientscripts.com/japanese.html) has ***logophonetic*** characters representing morphemes and
>   sounds.
>
> [Thai](http://www.ancientscripts.com/thai.html) has ***syllabic*** characters representing syllables.
>
> [Arabic](http://www.ancientscripts.com/arabic.html) has ***consonantal*** characters omitting vowel sounds.
>
> [Greek](http://www.ancientscripts.com/greek.html) has ***alphabetic*** characters similar yet distinct from
>   English.

The English alphabet is derived from Latin characters. In general, the characters of writing systems that do not use the Latin alphabet would most accurately be referred to as:

### ***[non-Latin characters](https://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/non-latin-characters-need-love)***, or [non-Latin ***script***](https://sites.google.com/site/worldfactsinc/Non-Latin-Script-Languages-Of-The-World)

For speakers of English, ***foreign characters***, or foreign ***script***, might work, since most would be inclined to say:

> *"It's all Greek to me!"*

---

The Greeks have a different idiom for [unintelligible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_to_me):

> Αυτά μου φαίνονται κινέζικα (Auto mou phainontai Kinedzika)
>
> translated: *To me this looks like Chinese*.

But what goes around gets around, as some Chinese refer to English as the [incomprehensible](http://www.omniglot.com/language/idioms/incomprehensible.php) language:

> 雞腸 (gāchèuhng)
>
> translated: *It's like chicken intestines.*

Which suggests a very informal alternative:

*[chicken scratch](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chicken+scratch)*?

Comment: *Foreign* doesn’t work very well, but *non-Latin letters* is fine, provided you capitalize it better. :)

Comment: Actually, I think your original comment (with an explanation that it is idiomatic) would be a nice addition to this answer, because _it's (all) Greek to me_ actually answers the question.

Comment: "It's Greek to me" is an idiom I've never heard of, It answers my question pretty well! All the addidtional info in your answer is helpful and interesting too. I think I'll stick with the above idiom though over "It's like chicken intestines" :P

Comment: You really weave an interesting answer @scotm!

Comment: [The directed graph of stereotypical incomprehensibility](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1024)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the context is, but you might use a more exotic word than letters -- glyphs, runes, characters, graphemes -- to suggest the symbols are unfamiliar. I was going to suggest ligatures as well, but that only applies when two or more graphemes are attached to each other such as æ. Still the word might come in handy depending on your purpose.